# How to make a confirmation page in Javascript with a user's inputs from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, confirmation

I'm attempting to make an HTML page with a script that will store the user's input in a query string, then display it back to the user with the appropriate labels/descriptions in a confirmation page. This is what I have so far, I'm very new to Javascript but have some experience with HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Bob's Pet Store</title>
  <script src="petshop.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <h1>Place your customer information below!</h1>
    <h2>Customer Information:</h2>
    <h3>Please enter the neccessary information.</h3>
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" /></p>
    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" /></p>
    <p>Email Address: <input type="text" id="address" /></p>
    <p>State: <input type="text" id="state" /></p>
    <p>Phone Number: <input type="text" id="number" /></p>
    <br></br>
    <br><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Information"></form>
  </br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet](https://www.keycdn.com/support/difference-between-java-and-javascript#:~:text=Java%20is%20to%20JavaScript%20as,%2C%20plugins%2C%20frameworks%2C%20etc.)

Comment: Are you looking for server-side help using Java? I'm confused by the question and the "Java" tag

Answer (score 1):

for this you could use confirm() and .value of the ID to get the job done like so:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
    function buttonFunction() {

var confirmationFNAME = document.getElementById("fname").value
confirm("Is, " + confirmationFNAME + " the right information?")

var confirmationLNAME = document.getElementById("lname").value
confirm("Is, " + confirmationLNAME + " the right information?")

var confirmationADDRESS = document.getElementById("address").value
confirm("Is, " + confirmationADDRESS + " the right information?")

var confirmationSTATE = document.getElementById("state").value
confirm("Is, " + confirmationSTATE + " the right information?")

var confirmationNUMBER = document.getElementById("number").value
confirm("Is, " + confirmationNUMBER + " the right information?")

}
```

**HTML (added onclick to button):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Bob's Pet Store</title>
  <script src="petshop.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <h1>Place your customer information below!</h1>
    <h2>Customer Information:</h2>
    <h3>Please enter the neccessary information.</h3>
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" /></p>
    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" /></p>
    <p>Email Address: <input type="text" id="address" /></p>
    <p>State: <input type="text" id="state" /></p>
    <p>Phone Number: <input type="text" id="number" /></p>
    <br></br>
    <br><input onclick = "buttonFunction()" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Information"></form>
  </br>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helped, if you got any bugs or problems feel free to reach out or comment.

Comment: Hey, I just realized that I used the `lname` id 3 times, you can just change that, I will edit the ansdwer.

Comment: I edited the answer, if there are anymore problems just reach out to me